how to resolve navigator.serviceWorker.ready problem?
In my Laravel project, I included a notification system and used a service worker with it. Everything works well on my localhost, but when I hosted it, it didn't work.
When the application is hosted, the service worker is successfully registered and functions as expected. However, during the execution of the service worker, the process halts or does not proceed beyond the line of code containing the console log statement 'console.log('test')'. This indicates that the code execution stops at this point, preventing further execution of subsequent code logic.
  <script>
// Request permission for notifications
Notification.requestPermission(function(permission) {
    if (permission === "granted") {
        console.log("Notification permission granted!");
    } else {
        console.log("Notification permission denied or not defined!");
    }
});

// Register the service worker
navigator.serviceWorker.register("{{ URL::asset('public/service-worker.js') }}").then(function(registration) {
    console.log('Service worker registered successfully:', registration);
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.error('Error registering service worker:', error);
});

// Check if the 'enable' key already exists in local storage
if (localStorage.getItem('enable')) {
    // If it exists, hide the button
    document.getElementById('enable').style.display = 'none';
} else {
    // If it doesn't exist, add event listener to the button
    document.getElementById('enable').addEventListener('click', () => {
        askForPermission();
        localStorage.setItem('enable', 'true');
        document.getElementById('enable').style.display = 'none';
    });
}

// Function to ask for notification permission
function askForPermission() {
    Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
        if (permission === 'granted') {
            // When permission is granted, register the service worker
            registerServiceWorker();
        } else {
            console.log("Notification permission denied!");
        }
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error('Error requesting notification permission:', error);
    });
}

// Function to register the service worker
function registerServiceWorker() {
    console.log('test');
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then((sw) => {
        sw.pushManager.subscribe({
            userVisibleOnly: true,
            applicationServerKey: "BFSaQyz3LSete1tR6WhZFXbvC2WfWRXDfeqA0j7sm2GesTOoruXKh9QMWC1XRsG25L4ZTqhjze0HnhIGEpKsIs8"
        }).then((subscription) => {
            console.log('Subscription successful:', subscription);
            saveSub(JSON.stringify(subscription));
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.error('Error subscribing to push notifications:', error);
        });
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error('Error retrieving service worker:', error);
    });
}

// Function to save the subscription on the server
function saveSub(sub) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '{{ URL('save-push-notification-sub') }}',
        data: {
            '_token': "{{ csrf_token() }}",
            'sub': sub,
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('Subscription saved on server successfully:', data);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.error('Error saving subscription on server:', error);
        }
    });
}

